# Visual Studio 2012 run current selected webform

Tags: visual-studio-2012

Really dumb question but it's annoying me because my VS2012 use to work like this:

When I run debug on the web application it used to open the current selected webform in the editor in the web browser.

Now the only way to change which one opens in the browser is that I must go to the webform I am busy on and click "Set As Start Page".

This makes it quite hard when I am working on multiple pages.

Please can someone tell me what setting I must change in VS to get it to work like it use to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the startup options of a web application goto:

Project->Properties->Web-> Select Current Page.